# Generate (my)sql(ite) create table using C# class?

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite

I'd like to markup a C# class kind of like the below. Is there any tools or libs using reflection to create a mysql or sqlite create table statement?

```
class MyTable {
    public int id;
    [FK("User")] //assumes table user, field id. FK("User.id") is just as fine
    public int user;
    [Index]
    public int flags;
    [unique]
    public string email;
    [unique, nullable]
    public string something_else;
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to do this without Entity Framework?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris: yes. I use dapper.